# Is the Bonus Money payday reward card subject to the offshore percentage?

Tags: payday-2

When you complete a mission, a fraction of your heist loot becomes spending cash and the rest goes to your offshore account. You get a reward card that can either be money, exp, a weapon mod, or a mask mod.

**Does the money reward card go directly to cash or is it subject to the offshore percentage?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes directly into your spending money.